# Kill a hanging sync from a cifs drive

Tags: cifs, kill

I copied a file to a cifs drive and instinctively ran a sync on it, which hung indefinitely. Strangely, I could successfully unmount/remount the drive without issues, making me think that the drive simply didn't respond to the sync call properly. It looks like the file is not growing, so the copy was successful (about the right size too).

This sync process is still hanging, and ignoring `kill -9`. I don't want to reboot the machine as it's a server.

Is there any way to coerce sync into thinking it's done? Is it normal for a cifs drive to behave this way?

EDIT: The host (running the sync) is Ubuntu 16.04. I don't know how to determine the SMB/cifs OS but I have a feeling it's windows since the drive was originally for windows users.

I left it over the weekend, and upon returning (reattaching to tmux), it's still hanging

Another edit:
Journalctl is eating CPU, and giving 1000's of the following message per second:

```
Apr 08 08:14:49 [Server name] audit[855]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="recvmsg" profile="snap.canonical-livepatcchd" pid=855 comm="canonical-livep" family="netlink" sock_type="raw" protocol=15 requested_mask="receive" denied_mask="receive"
```

Edit: Doesn't look like I have "vote to close" privileges here, but I've found a similar question.

[Kill a hanging sync from a cifs drive](https://serverfault.com/questions/961718/kill-a-hanging-sync-from-a-cifs-drive)

Comment: Which operating system for the SMB (fka CIFS) client and host?

Comment: Host is Ubuntu 1604 (will edit question). How do I find out the cifs OS?

Comment: Check the state of the process in top or htop. I suppose it's in "Z" (zombie) state. If that's the case, there's nothing you can do but wait and hope, or reboot.

Comment: I've since rebooted the server when I had the chance. Is there really no way to kill a zombie process? Clearly if it's showing up in top the process manager has a way of identifying it and its memory footprint, should there not be a "forcefully deallocate all memory and remove from the process table"?